# How to add an unlisted font in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-fonts

I really want the font *UnifrakturCook*. I tried the [Extensis fonts](http://www.extensis.com/font-management/benefits-of-font-management/fonts-for-google-docs/) add-on, and it's not working. How can I get the font onto my Google Doc?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add a custom font to Docs because Docs uses special web-based fonts, not locally stored proprietary fonts. There are many fonts available in Docs, however [in some languages, you can add new fonts to your font list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1663349).

1. On your computer, open a document in Google Docs.
2. At the top, click the font name to open the font list.
3. At the bottom of the list, click More fonts.
4. Browse or search for new fonts.
5. Click a font to add it to your "My fonts" list.
6. To sort your fonts or change how they appear in your list, use the "Show" and "Sort" arrows.
7. Click Ok.

Regarding your specific wish to have - try typing uni... an you will get UnifrakturMaguntia, which is close.